# why is the front of my sculpt red?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, sculpting

i was sculpting a head when all of a sudden i think i mightve pressed something by accident and the front of my mesh disappeared. Then it came back after messing around pressing stuff but the part thats missing is now red. i dont know what it does or why its like that.[image] im in blender 3.0 cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably used the *Face Sets* brush by accident (it's a kind of mask):

[image]

You can disable it, go into the header menu > *Face Sets > Face Set from Visible*:

[image]